# NiFi: How to develop a JUnit test of NiFi controller service?

Tags: junit, apache-nifi

I am developing a NiFi controller service, and this controller service has a property of another controller service which is dbcpservice.
Accoding to the source code in github.com/apache/nifi, controller service test depends on processor test too, that means define a TestProcessor which has a property of self-defined controller service, and then operate the the controller service through this processor.
But in my case, my controller service's property is another controller service(dbcpservice), I do not know how to write a junit test to set the controller service.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple processor via anonymous inner classes (or named classes) in your test in order to exercise the behavior of your controller service. For example, [`DBCPServiceTest`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-dbcp-service-bundle/nifi-dbcp-service/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/dbcp/DBCPServiceTest.java#L52) does this by defining `TestProcessor` alongside the test class. All that test processor needs is a property descriptor which accepts a controller service of the same type as the system under test (SUT) -- in this case, your custom controller service.

If you're asking how to configure your custom service (`CustomService` from here on), you pass parameters to the `TestRunner` instance, like so:

```
final TestRunner runner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(TestProcessor.class);
final CustomService service = new CustomService();
service.setNestedService(new NestedService());
final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
runner.addControllerService("custom-service-id", service, properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Andy's answer - you could also create a test processor with Mockito:

```
AbstractProcessor processor = new Mockito().spy(AbstractProcessor.class);
TestRunner testRunner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(processor);
```